# PanGestureHandler state change interrupt gesture

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am using **PanGestureHandler** from react-native-gesture-handler, everything is working fine but when the state is changed inside onGestureEvent, the **PanGestureHandler** stop working and I have to release my finger and touch again to start the gesture. Please check the code below that describe my problem:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {PanGestureHandler, State} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import styles from '../Styles/HomeStyles.js';

const PanResp = () => {
  const [testState, setTestState] = useState('State....');

  const gestureEventHandler = ({nativeEvent}) => {
    if (nativeEvent.x + nativeEvent.translationX <= 74) {
      setTestState('New State');
    } else {
      console.log('X Position => ', nativeEvent.x);
    }
  };

  const onDragRelease = () => {
    console.log('Drag Release');
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={gestureEventHandler}
        onEnded={onDragRelease}>
        <FastImage
          style={styles.imgIcon}
          source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/LwCYmcM.gif'}}
        />
        <FastImage
          style={styles.imgIcon}
          source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/k5jMsaH.gif'}}
        />
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PanResp;
```

**Note:** The above codes work fine, and when the state update and I release my fingers from touch no DragRelease event is firing, and also the PanGestureHandler not respond to touch any more. I am stuck at this point from past week.